# run server-requiring angular2 app on device

Tags: cordova, angular, server, localhost, ionic2

I'm working on a cordova cross-platform project, and I need some help.

The idea was to convert an angular2 web app into mobile app. I use ionic2 framework because that works with angular2. After I copied the files from the "dist" folder (where the angular2 app was built to) to the blank app's "www" folder, I imported the cordova and ionic scripts to the new index.html file.

It runs with `ionic run browser` or `ionic serve -l` BUT when I run it on real devices (android, windows) the scripts don't load.

I know that the problem is connected to the lack of server, because the original webapp does the same, when I don't run a server in the background. When I do , I can connect on `localhost:3000`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

2 hours later I solved my problem. It didn't have anything to do with the server. 
I had set `<base href="/">` on the index page, but debugging with cordova helped me to figure it out that it should have been `<base href="./">`.

Now everything works fine!